# iText 7: How can I insert diagrams into a `Document`?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.2.1.

According to the documentation, I can only find elements like `Image`, `Div`, `List`, `Paragraph`, `Table` can be inserted into `Document`.

I want to draw some diagrams and insert it into my document. I need them to be part of my content stream. The existing `PdfCanvas` or `Canvas` can not do that. They seems to accept only absolute positions.

Is there a way inserting diagrams in iText 7?

Comment: Well, `PdfCanvas` gives you access to all low-level instructions available in PDF content streams. Thus, you can draw diagrams using those instructions. Alternatively. if your diagrams are created in some other format, you have some options: (A) bitmap images - you can easily draw bitmap images using `Canvas` or `PdfCanvas` methods; (B) HTML (plain HTML, without JavaScript) - use the [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/convert-html-css-to-pdf-pdfhtml) addon; (C) SVG - use the svg core module.

Comment: @mkl I want to draw diagrams using `PdfCanvas` instructions. Is it possible that I don't have to specify absolute position, and the diagram automatically follow the previous paragraph, and next paragraphs automatically follow this diagram. Is SVG the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you clarified

> I want to draw diagrams using `PdfCanvas` instructions. Is it possible that I don't have to specify absolute position, and the diagram automatically follow the previous paragraph, and next paragraphs automatically follow this diagram. Is SVG the only way to do this?

You can create your diagram in a `PdfFormXObject` which has its own coordinate system. `PdfCanvas` instances can also be constructed for form XObjects.

Then you can wrap that XObject in an iText `Image` which in turn you can add to an iText `Document` to be automatically positioned.

So for a `PdfDocument pdfDocument` and a `Document document`:

```java
PdfFormXObject xobject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle([... area for your diagram ...]));
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(xobject, pdfDocument);
[... draw diagram on pdfCanvas ...]
Image image = new Image(xobject);
document.add(image);
```